# D3 transition not working after update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a transition after drawing squares next to already drawn squares in my SVG container. My code to draw new squares next to the already drawn ones is as follow (not working):

```
var calculation = numToDrawSquares - numDrawnSquares;
var selectedGroup = d3.select("#" + source + "Group");

// Loop to draw the missing squares
for(var j = 0; j < calculation; j++)
{
    var draw = selectedGroup.append("rect")
            .attr("class", source)
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("width", 15)
            .attr("height", 15)
            .style("fill", color);

    draw.transition()
            .attr("y", y)
            .duration(3000)
            .delay(250);
}
```

My code for the already drawn squares is as follow (working):

```
        // SVG container
        container = d3.select("#" + source)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("class", "svgContainer")
                .attr("width", 81)
                .attr("height", 600);

        rectangleGroup = container.append("g")
                .attr("class", source + "_group" + " tooltip")
                .attr("id", source + "Group")

            // Drawing the squares
            rectangle = rectangleGroup.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", source)
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", 0)
                    .attr("width", 15)
                    .attr("height", 15)
                    .style("fill", "#" + color)
                    .transition()
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .delay(250);
```

Does anyone know why the transition in my first code snippet is not working? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: codepen or similar could help to find a solution

Comment: The for loop in the first code block is not the way to add components with d3. If you have a firm grasp of enter/update/exit, this stuff will be much easier for you. Take a look at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Comment: @lhoworko I understand that my code is not the perfect/correct in that sense, I am still learning. I will have to modify my code to use data() and enter(), which I will do at one point. However, the code in the second snippet is also located in a for loop and working just fine with the transition. Why is that? Thank you!

Comment: @tgirgin You're transitioning `y` from y to y -- you won't see anything because the value doesn't change.

Comment: @lars-kotthoff Thank you, that fixed it!